# SocketTimeOutException not thrown when making a rest-call inside AWS lamda (java)

Tags: aws-lambda

In my current project we are using aws-lambda to make a rest call to external service and consume the response. Happy path works fine but when it comes to connection-timeout or socket-timeout it is not working as expected. Little more details below

- When making a call to external system and if the read-timeout scenario happens (external system connection got established but did not receive any response from the system within 15 sec) the aws lambda keeps waiting for the response till lambda-timeout (25 sec) and returns error.
- But I expect the rest-call code invoked within lamda to throw the SocketTimeOutException or related one which is not happening.
- Same thing, when I tried using a sample java code (using apache's http-client implementation which is what I have used in lambda) it works perfectly fine and I am getting proper exception thrown.
- Initially we tried with jersey implementation for making rest-call and thought this is having issue and changed to http-client implementation, but none of them thrown the exception as it does in sample java code.

Please let me know your suggestions or solutions if faced already.
Below is the code snippet that I use in both lambda as well as sample program for making the rest call. (this whole block is wrapped under try-catch)

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
RequestJSONObject request = new RequestJSONObject();
//setting required request payload
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(request); 
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonStr));
post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");     

RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
  .setConnectTimeout(1000)
  .setSocketTimeout(3000).build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = 
HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Thanks,
Ganesh Karthik C.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet of the REST call?

Comment: I have just added code sample. please check

Comment: Thank you! I am unfortunately not proficient with Java but I'm hoping that the code might help contributors who are! 